# BuddyPress Task System

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am currently looking at a project that requires a task management system with certain specific requirements. Before I begin wasting a ton of time reinventing the wheel, I figured I would search around for something that meets the bill. I haven't found anything yet so I figured I would ask here as a last resort.

The site is a BuddyPress site that needs a "task board" feature where by:

1: User A can post a task to be done.
2: User B can accept that task to be done.
3: When User B finished whatever was requested in the task, they mark the task as done and User A gets a notification.

If there is a preexisting plugin that is "close enough" to this idea, I can always hack it to meet my exact needs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for WordPress/BuddyPress called "CollabPress" that was just released with BuddyPress support.  I think it will fit your needs.

http://buddypress.org/community/groups/collabpress/